# I dont want to see any folder or application on desktop

Tags: .desktop

I want to have folders present in desktop directory but it should not be actually displayed on the desktop.

Here I took a screen-shot of my desktop left side is what I see and Right side is what I want to see

[image: before and after]

Answer (score 2):

To do from cli use-

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

else you can do it directly by serching dconf editor in dash then navigate to

```
org-gnome-desktop-background
```

and then uncheck show-desktop icon . [image: dconf editor]

If you cant see the image ,just right click on it and save it and then see.